# In exim's queue, how can I see when each message will be retried?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, exim

I don't want to force a retry just yet, I want to see when I should check the queue again.  (Without having to mentally evaluate the retry configuration.)  mailq only shows how long each message has been waiting, not how long until the retry time is reached.  Is there a way to get exim to tell me when that will be?

Comment: Why even care? You can trust Exim that it will retry as configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exim ships with a utility, [exinext](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-exim_utilities.html#SECTfinindret), that will show you the first, last, and next retry times of a single message:

```
exinext domain|address|messageID
```

It seems that you could use [exim_dumpdb](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-exim_utilities.html#SECThindatmai) and post-process the output, as exinext does, if you wanted to see information about the whole queue at once.

Comment: Thanks, that does what I need.  I made a little Ruby script to automate it - probably too inefficient for large queues, but sufficient for me.  (Bah, the lack of multiline comments is not helping)

`mailq = "/usr/bin/mailq"; 
exinext = "/usr/sbin/exinext"; 

`#{mailq}`.each_line do |q|; 
 puts q; 
 q=q.strip; 
 unless ""==q or q.include?(" "); 
  `#{exinext} \"#{q}\"`.each_line do |n|; 
   print "\t\t"; 
   puts n; 
  end; 
 end; 
end;